# Disable/Override bodyparser behaviour

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, body-parser

Can we disable or override the bodyparser after injecting it as middleware to express app?

in one file(not editable, done by framework) 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
export app;

in other file i'm importing app and here i want to disable bodyParser for one of the routes. Is there any way i can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// export file
// ...

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // check if the path need body parser or not
  if (BlackList.includes(req.path)) {
    bodyParser.json()
  }
  next()
});

// ...
```

```js
// import file
// ...

// some router
BlackList.push('anyway')
app.get('/anyway', function (req, res, next) {
  // your code...
})

// ...
```

Comment: I agree but is there any other way where we can nullify/remove the bodyParser behaviour without any extra variable? 
I mean after injecting it as a middleware like
app.use(bodyParser);
app.use(remove bodyParser);

Comment: Like for node http Server, we can remove listeners attached to it. server.removeListener(.....)